# $c = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query($q));

Tags: php, mysql

I was wondering if this

```
$c = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("select * from action_6_weekly where code='$code'"));
```

is considered valid PHP?

Or do I need to do the following?

```
$r = mysql_query("select * from action_6_weekly where code='$code'");
$c = mysql_num_rows($r);
```

this is what i am actually doing:

```
if($entry == '9')
    $c = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("select * from action_6_5pts where code='$code'")) or die ('MYSQL ERROR: '.mysql_error().' in '.__FILE__.' on '.__LINE__.'.');
elseif($entry == 'a')
    $c = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("select * from action_6_10pts where code='$code'")) or die ('MYSQL ERROR: '.mysql_error().' in '.__FILE__.' on '.__LINE__.'.');
else
    $c = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("select * from action_6_weekly where code='$code'")) or die ('MYSQL ERROR: '.mysql_error().' in '.__FILE__.' on '.__LINE__.'.');

if($c > 0) 
    $waiting_for_reply = false;
```

Comment: TBH guys, all im interested in with this is finding out if a row exists, i dont actually care how many rows there are, just if there is 1 or more.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is generally better to do it on separate lines and assign it a variable.

This way you can work with the result easier. But to get a count of rows, if that is all you are looking for, this would be better and more efficient:

```
$r = mysql_query("select count(id) from action_6_weekly where code='$code'");
$c = mysql_result($r, 0, 0);
```

Where the id is the unique identifier field to count.

EDIT:
Given that you do not care how many rows there are, just that it exists:

```
$r = mysql_query("select code from action_6_weekly where code='$code' LIMIT 1");
if (mysql_num_rows($r) > 0) {
    // echo it exists!
}
```

Answer (score 5):

It's valid (after all it executes), but is ugly.

Not to mention

```
$r = mysql_query("select COUNT(*) AS cnt from action_6_weekly where code='$code'");
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($r);
$c = $row['cnt'];
```

will likely put less strain on your database.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use the return value of one function as a parameter value for another function. So in your case both variants are equal.

But you need to be careful when doing that as part of a condition that might be tested multiple times like in a `while` loop. Because the condition in the following is executed with every iteration:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT …"))) {
    // …
}
```

This will yield an infinite loop as `mysql_query("SELECT …")` is executed with every iteration and will probably return a valid result set every time.

But you shouldn’t select all data if you just want to get the number of rows. Use the [aggregate function `COUNT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_count) to let MySQL count the rows for you.

Answer (score 0):

It is about **readability** and **brevity** though you can use either, I would go with this one though because it looks cleaner:

```
$r = mysql_query("select * from action_6_weekly where code='$code'");
$c = $c = mysql_num_rows($r);
```

Answer (score 0):

Variables are placeholders for data. Therefore, if you can write

```
$x = 4;
function($x);
```

you can also write

```
function(4);
```

But it's easier to later commit changes and add data the former way. Comments also help.